# Json data size limitation

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have json data that is about 1,000,000 character length and about 1.04MB size.
I have JavaScript program (with d3.js)that must parse json data by eval() function.
Is my jsondata too big for Json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960378/maximum-data-file-size-for-d3-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is similar to other data formats like XML - if you need to transmit more data, you just send more data and process.
for more clarification see this thread:[Is there a limit on how much JSON can hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262376/is-there-a-limit-on-how-much-json-can-hold)